# How to reference a slick grid with jquery notation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, slickgrid

I'm working with a javascript library called slick grid to display a grid on a webpage. I need to send the grid information via ajax to a server. My problem is I need to used jquery notation to access the grid.

Here is the div grid:

```
<div id="myGrid" style="width:100%;height:300px;"></div>
```

Here is the javascript I'm using:

```
var grid;

$(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        data[i] = {
            pbc_id: "00" + i,
            task: "Task " + i,
            due_date: "02/02/2017"
        };
    }

    grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);

    grid.setSelectionModel(new Slick.CellSelectionModel());
    grid.registerPlugin(new Slick.AutoTooltips());

    // set keyboard focus on the grid
    grid.getCanvasNode().focus();

    var copyManager = new Slick.CellCopyManager();
    grid.registerPlugin(copyManager);

    copyManager.onPasteCells.subscribe(function (e, args) {
        if (args.from.length !== 1 || args.to.length !== 1) {
            throw "This implementation only supports single range copy and paste operations";
        }

        var from = args.from[0];
        var to = args.to[0];
        var val;
        for (var i = 0; i <= from.toRow - from.fromRow; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j <= from.toCell - from.fromCell; j++) {
                if (i <= to.toRow - to.fromRow && j <= to.toCell - to.fromCell) {
                    val = data[from.fromRow + i][columns[from.fromCell + j].field];
                    data[to.fromRow + i][columns[to.fromCell + j].field] = val;
                    grid.invalidateRow(to.fromRow + i);
                }
            }
        }
        grid.render();
    });

    grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe(function (e, args) {
        var item = args.item;
        var column = args.column;
        grid.invalidateRow(data.length);
        data.push(item);
        grid.updateRowCount();
        grid.render();
    });
})

var DocumentViewModel = function () {

    var self = this;

    self.sendGridData = function () {
        var data = $("myGrid");

        //TODO: access the grid data and convert the data to a json string

        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: '/MyService/SubmitRequest',
            data: ,
            success: function (response) {
               alert("success");
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, exceptionThrown) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    };
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: [trying to access the grid variable where my todo is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ix5p3.png)

Comment: var Data_Grid = grid.getData(); <------With that line retrieve the contents of the grid.........

var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(Data_Grid);  <-----And convert it to json

Comment: for some reason I cant access the grid variable where the TODO is.

Comment: I'm using it too and it's working  O_o

Comment: see the picture in my edit:

Comment: ```grid``` is declared in the global namespace and hence _should_ be available at your TODO point. but it's clearly not, as evidenced by your screenshot. so your code is not as you have written above.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to recreate your problem above. Had to add some code to get the example to execute as is. It seems your main problem is that though the grid variable is declared in the global address space, iether the contents of DocumentViewModel cannot access it because everything inside DocumentViewModel is private to this function or perhaps your DocumentViewModel is executing before the other code is declared (more likely) however you've not shown how or WHEN you are triggering DocumentViewModel so I can't tell you for sure.

But by moving DocumentViewModel inside '$(function () {' finally the variable was found and the grid was accessible.

I'll paste my code below which includes yours plus the extra I added to get it to execute.

```
<html>
<head>
<h1>myGrid SO Question Test</h1>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/lib/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js"></script>
<style src="http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css"></style>
<script src="http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/slick.core.js"></script>
<script src="http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/slick.grid.js"></script>

<script src="http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/slick.editors.js"></script>
<script src="http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/slick.formatters.js"></script>
<script src="http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/slick.dataview.js"></script>
<script src="http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/plugins/slick.cellselectionmodel.js"></script>

<script src="http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/plugins/slick.cellrangeselector.js"></script>
<script src="http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/plugins/slick.cellrangedecorator.js"></script>
<script src="http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/plugins/slick.rowselectionmodel.js"></script>
<script src="http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/plugins/slick.autotooltips.js"></script>
<script src="http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/plugins/slick.cellcopymanager.js"></script>

<script src="my.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myGrid" style="width:100%;height:300px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
$(function () {

    var grid;

    // Addition Start
     var columns = [{
     id: "column",
     name: "",
     field: "column",
     //selectable: false,
     focusable: false
    },
               {
     id: "data",
     name: "Data",
     field: "data"
    }];

    var options = {
     enableCellNavigation: true,
     enableColumnReorder: false      
    };
    // Addition End


    var data = [];              // Addition
    for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        data[i] = {
            pbc_id: "00" + i,
            task: "Task " + i,
            due_date: "02/02/2017"
        };
    }

    grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);

    grid.setSelectionModel(new Slick.CellSelectionModel());
    grid.registerPlugin(new Slick.AutoTooltips());

    // set keyboard focus on the grid
    grid.getCanvasNode().focus();

    var copyManager = new Slick.CellCopyManager();
    grid.registerPlugin(copyManager);

    copyManager.onPasteCells.subscribe(function (e, args) {
        if (args.from.length !== 1 || args.to.length !== 1) {
            throw "This implementation only supports single range copy and paste operations";
        }

        var from = args.from[0];
        var to = args.to[0];
        var val;
        for (var i = 0; i <= from.toRow - from.fromRow; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j <= from.toCell - from.fromCell; j++) {
                if (i <= to.toRow - to.fromRow && j <= to.toCell - to.fromCell) {
                    val = data[from.fromRow + i][columns[from.fromCell + j].field];
                    data[to.fromRow + i][columns[to.fromCell + j].field] = val;
                    grid.invalidateRow(to.fromRow + i);
                }
            }
        }
        grid.render();
    });

    grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe(function (e, args) {
        var item = args.item;
        var column = args.column;
        grid.invalidateRow(data.length);
        data.push(item);
        grid.updateRowCount();
        grid.render();
    });

    // Move DocumentViewModel inside "$(function ()" 
    var DocumentViewModel = function () {

    var self = this;

    self.sendGridData = function () {
        var data = $("myGrid");

        //TODO: access the grid data and convert the data to a json string

        var Data_Grid = grid.getData(); 
        var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(Data_Grid); 

        // $.ajax({
            // async: true,
            // type: "POST",
            // dataType: "json",
            // url: '/MyService/SubmitRequest',
            // data: ,
            // success: function (response) {
               // alert("success");
            // },
            // error: function (xhr, textStatus, exceptionThrown) {
                // alert("error");
            // }
        // });
    };

    self.sendGridData();    // Addition Trigger our local function
};

// Addition : Trigger our function to prove we can access the grid's data
DocumentViewModel();

})
```